# How to provide rating in taxi application?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have to provide a rating in  a taxi application, The Xpath of that inspected rating element is

```
//*[@id="trip-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
```

How do i select 3rd or any of the star out of 5 ? anyone pls help me

Comment: can you please post the html code here?

Comment: You provide the xpath you tried, but to make an efective question we would need the html it was executed against. Check the [mcve].

Comment: Without html code, I can only suggest you to 'Inspect' the star you need. Then in *Developer Tools* in *Elements* right click on your star html code and do *Copy -> Copy XPath*. You can do this in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

We need the full html code as stated above but most likely each star have its own xpath so you need either 5 xpaths (assuming you have 5* rating) or need to append to the xpath depending on the stars you want to give (in switch statement presumably).